# Empty QueryTable

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub testing()
Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql As String, qt As 
QueryTable, bookSheet As Object, sqlstring As String

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & "I:\Desktop" & "\" & "WebPropertiesSummaryQuery.xlsm" & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
    .Open
    End With

sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$] WHERE Rating = 'WBS PWT'"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Source = sql
rs.ActiveConnection = cn
rs.Open sql

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).Activate
Set bookSheet = Workbooks("WebPropertiesSummaryQuery.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set qt = bookSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, _
Destination:=Range("A1"), sql:=sql)

MsgBox ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Count

rs.Close
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

I am trying to generate a table that uses an SQL style query. All this is done within a single workbook, where the data that is queried is in sheet 2 and the querytable to be displayed on sheet 3. With this code, I can see that I am creating a new querytable, however the sheet is blank. I presume that there might be an issue with the QueryTables.Add line because when I add this code to test my recordset it displays the correct values.

```
Do
    output = output & rs(0) & ";" & rs(1) & ";" & rs(2) & vbNewLine
    Debug.Print rs(0); ";" & rs(1) & ";" & rs(2)
    rs.Movenext
Loop Until rs.EOF
MsgBox output
```

Comment: Do you need a .Refresh on the query? Like Activesheet.QueryTables(1).Refresh ...

Comment: That `Do...Loop Until` loop to dump `rs` content is overkill: there's a `Range.CopyFromRecordset` method for doing quite exactly that... you could dump the `rs` onto a throw-away worksheet instead of printing to debug output.

Comment: @QHarr Yea I had that but it gave me a 1004 runtime error. Pardon by noobness but what's the difference between .Refresh and manually refreshing in the data ribbon? Cuz I've tried manually refreshing it and I still get a blank worksheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the following data on sheet2:
[image]

I get the following data on sheet3:
[image]

With the following code:

```
    Sub testing()
        Dim cn As Object
        Dim rs As Object
        Dim sql As String
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim wsEndTarget As Worksheet

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set wsEndTarget = wb.Sheets("Sheet3")
        Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        With cn
            .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
            .connectionString = "Data Source=" & _   
            "C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\sqlSheet.xlsm" & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
            .Open
        End With

        sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$] WHERE Rating = 'WBS PWT'"

        Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        rs.Source = sql
        rs.ActiveConnection = cn
        rs.Open sql

        wsEndTarget.Activate
        For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            wsEndTarget.Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
        Next
        wsEndTarget.Range(wsEndTarget.Cells(1, 1), _
            wsEndTarget.Cells(1, rs.Fields.Count)).Font.Bold = True
        wsEndTarget.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs

        wb.Close
        rs.Close
        cn.Close
        Set wb = Nothing
        Set wsEndTarget = Nothing
        Set cn = Nothing
        Set rs = Nothing
    End Sub
```